# submit a list become null in the post + MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post, html-helper, form-submit

I have a ViewModel:

```
public class RegistrationViewModel
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public ConfigurationParamValue CountryParam { get; set; }
    public string Civility { get; set; }
    public ConfigurationParamValue CivilityParam { get; set; }
    [FirstNameValidator(Category = "Registration", IsLocal = false )]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public ConfigurationParamValue FirstNameParam { get; set; }
    [LastNameValidator(Category = "Registration", IsLocal = false)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<int> Days { get; set; }
    public int SelectedDay{ get; set; }
    public List<Month> Months { get; set; }
    public Month SelectedMonth { get; set; }
    public List<int> Years { get; set; }
    public int SelectedYear { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

I create a view with this viewmodel :

```
@model Registration.Front.Web.Models.RegistrationViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>RegistrationViewModel</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Country)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Civility)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Civility)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Civility)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BirthDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedDay, new SelectList(Model.Days))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BirthDate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Occupation)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Occupation)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Occupation)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ZipCode)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ZipCode)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ZipCode)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CGV)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CGV)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CGV)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Optin)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Optin)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Optin)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CNIL)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CNIL)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CNIL)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

this is My contoller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
        List<int> listDays = new List<int>(){1, 2, 3};
        return View(new RegistrationViewModel() { Days=listDays });
        }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index( RegistrationViewModel rvm)
       {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
          { return RedirectToAction("Welcome"); }

       return View(rvm);
       }

public ActionResult Welcome()
      {
      return View();
      }
```

My problem is in the post, the property Days of the viewmodel is null!!!!! How can i correct this?

Comment: Which is the day property? you mean List<int> Days?

Comment: yes rvm.day in the submit is null

Comment: you don't have a property in the RegistrationViewModel called day. You have Days and SelectedDay. What property is actually coming back null?

Comment: name of property is Days, i get in the submit rvm.Days==null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your View you are not rendering Days inside form

Render hidden fields inside form with name="Days" like

`foreach(var day in @Model.Days)
{
<input type="hidden" name="Days" />
}`

copy the above code and paste it after
`<div class="editor-field">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CNIL)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CNIL)
 </div>`

Now,when you submit, the Days values will also submitted to the Post method and you will get values in Days List.

Comment: Ok that's great. What if we want to remove and element of list in View?